# Can Azure change a users OID?

Tags: azure-active-directory

we are going to be storing users information in Cosmos. Storing their information against their email address is not an option. Instead, we are looking at storing against OID.

Can Azure change a users OID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No. `oid` claim or `ObjectId` property is immutable as well as Unique, so it should never change as well as uniquely identify the relevant directory object.

Special note only about oid claim for user object.. if a single user exists in multiple tenants, the user will contain a different object ID in each tenant - they are considered different accounts, even though the user logs into each account with the same credentials.

Here are a few reference links for this part:
 1. `oid` claim for User - [Azure AD Token Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens)

[image]

2. [Service principal entity reference in Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity)

   [image]
3. [Service principal entity reference in the beta version for Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/serviceprincipal)